# AVERAGEIF function on different cells in different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to average 4 non-zero values from 4 different worksheets.
I've tried these functions but it returns an #ERROR!.

=AVERAGEIF([Monday!I2,Tuesday!I2,Wednesday!I2,Thursday!I2],"<>0")

=AVERAGEIF((Monday!I2,Tuesday!I2,Wednesday!I2,Thursday!I2),"<>0")

=SUMIF((Monday!I2,Tuesday!I2,Wednesday!I2,Thursday!I2),"<>0")/COUNTIF((Monday!I2,Tuesday!I2,Wednesday!I2,Thursday!I2),"<>0")

I think there is a problem with the range that is messed up because Excel doesn't recognize it. Is there a way to average these numbers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDIRECT with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday"}&"'!I2"),"<>0"))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday"}&"'!I2"),"<>0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the entries in those cells are strictly **non-negative**, I would prefer a *non-volatile* set-up which also does not require the creation of an array of worksheet names.

`=SUM(Monday:Thursday!I2)/INDEX(FREQUENCY(Monday:Thursday!I2,0),2)`

which assumes that *Monday* and *Thursday* are the leftmost and rightmost of the sheets to be interrogated.

***Edit***: If those cells *can* contain negative numbers, it may still be worth trying:

`=SUM(Monday:Thursday!I2)/SUM(INDEX(FREQUENCY(Monday:Thursday!I2,{-1,0}),{1,3}))`

where, in this case, it is assumed that none of the entries are `>-1` and `<0`.